# what is mysql binlog dump in show processlist

Tags: mysql, processlist

When I did `show processlist` in mysql I got list of process. One of the process with **binlog dump** running from quit long time.
What is **binlog dump**? do I need to kill this. what happen if i kill this process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally we are doing show process when we are getting error `too many connections`, but in my case Mysql is not responding intermittently. So i thought of looking into the processes if there is any long running query, so that I can kill it.
I got **binlog dump** under `Command` column in process list.

`Command` shows the type of command the thread is currently executing.

**binlog dump** is a thread on a master server for sending binary log contents to a slave server.

If need more information on different values of `Command` you can refer to:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/thread-commands.html

For **show process**

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html

Comment: So is it safe to say that in a master/slave setup, "Binlog Dump" will constantly be running on master?

Answer (score 2):

Its a process that constantly runs on the master server needed for replication. You should generally ignore this process, it should be harmless.